# WM_GETTEXT returning only single character

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm a chemist new to coding and am working on a script to help me automatically process some of my data. The code I'm working on right now involves using WM_GETTEXT to grab the title of a window handle. However, right now the char buffer is only grabbing a single character, rather than the whole title. It looks like someone several years ago had a similar problem (link: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/58207/), which suggests the issue may be related to mixing data types. I tried switching to a TCHAR as suggested, but cannot compile on doing so (receive error that I cannot convert from "const char[1] to TCHAR[254]). Here's the code I'm using:

```
int textLen = (int)SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
std::cout << "The handle length is: " << textLen << std::endl;
const int bufferSize = 254;
char textBuffer[bufferSize] = "";
SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)bufferSize, (LPARAM)textBuffer);
std::cout << "The handle title is: " << textBuffer << std::endl;
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm working in Microsoft Visual Studio, which I think may be part of the problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: `wchar_t` and `L""`. You're getting an UCS-2 string crammed into a narrow array.

Comment: "working on a script" - terminology; C++ is *not* a scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `SendMessageA` instead of `SendMessage` - that indicates you are using char not WCHAR (i.e. what TCHAR really might have been).

Alternatively, use wide-character versions of `std::cout`, which is `std::wcout` and use TCHAR/WCHAR throughout (including textBuffer declaration).

In essence, you're mixing wide strings with old-school strings.

Comment: For the wcout thing to work, OP would need to declare `textBuffer` to be of type `wchar_t`.

Comment: Thanks, SendMessageA worked! Can you explain a bit more about why, please? I'm very new to this and get mixed up easily between data types.

Comment: Sure! The "A" at the end meant "i'm using char". If it had "W" at the end it would say "I'm using WCHAR" (wide characters). It doesn't know the difference because in SendMessage we need to cast the string buffer to an LPARAM.

Comment: I think that makes sense. Thanks again! Are there any good resources out there for learning more about WinAPI? Windows Dev Center often doesn't give enough information for a newbie.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know. It's not used so much these days so online tutorials are unlikely to be found.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct, but you might want to consider using [GetWindowText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta) instead of sending the message.

With GetWindowText, whether you use the -A or -W suffix, you'd get some type safety, which might have helped you avoid this problem in the first place.

In some cases, GetWindowText can return the title even if the process that owns the target window is hung or not responding to messages in a timely fashion.

Comment: In this case, I don't think I can use GetWindowText since my window isn't owned by the current process. I could be mistaken, but when I tried to use it previously I encountered an unhandled exception.

Comment: If it's a top-level window, then GetWindowText is fine (and preferred) if it's in another process.  If it's a control window (e.g., a static text field) in another process, then GetWindowText will return a null string.  If you got an unhandled exception, there's a bug in your code.